# Micromax A60 releated quetion

Tags: recovery-mode

I am using a Micromax A60 phone which just hangs. I tried to use stock recovery which showed the following options:

```
Android System Recovery
-reboot system now
-apply sdcard : update.zip
-wipe data/factory reset
-wipe cache partition
-finding packege
-opennig packege
-verification failed
-installation abord
```

I am not clear what to do further here.  I had downloaded and placed 2.1 Éclair ROM in my SD card and it is not working and it is not install directly phone.

What else I can do to bring my phone back to usable state?

Comment: I can see you're in a bit of a panic about that, but you need to calm down and describe the problem clearly so we can understand. What exactly happened, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I  modified the question completely as it was in an highly inappropriate state. Rohit, in case if my wording deviates from your intention, just leave a comment and I'll update it.

Comment: The last option (wipe cache) is the only one always being safe, and never hurts in case of instability/hangs. So regardless what your issue is, you can for sure give that a try. Apart from that, as the previous comments already suggested, you need to provide more details for us to be able to help you. E.g. when did the problem start, what did you do last, anything installed lately, or maybe even fiddling with the system using root-powers?

Comment: Before 20 days....Strat this problem....and I am last install 2.1 Eclair version...!
Please help me yaar....I mean body....!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1212785) is MIUI rom for Micromax a60

Please read Install instructions carefully in this thread.

If you want to stock rom then its [here](http://androidxda.com/download-micromax-stock-rom-models)

Comment: Thanks for You will be given me MIUI version link for A60 I hope it will be work....?